# I did a beginner project creating a calculator, and pushed to Github. Where do I locate my code?

Tags: python, git

I did a beginner project using Pycharm creating a calculator using Python. I then shared the project on Github. But I cannot seem to find my code on Github. Only see the .idea (folder) .gitignore (page) and .README.md (pages) under the code tab, but no page with the code.

Comment: Use the command line first. Then you can debug with pycharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you have added and committed, before pushing.

Type git show to see the content of your last commit.

You need to add and commit your sources, not just `.idea` or `.gitignore`.

If your sources do not show, check if they are not ignored by mistake with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- a/source/file
```

Comment: Thank you. I had ignored the code by mistake. I resolved it by restarting the whole process on PyCharm, then committing and pushing everything together.

Answer (score 1):

Your repo should pretty closely resemble the directory on your computer, so I’d start there. Does the file path to your code on your computer have some overlap with the repo? If so, then VonD is probably right—you may have inadvertently not pushed it or added it to your ignore file.

If, however, the file bears no resemblance at all to your repo, then you’ve probably just saved the file to the wrong place by mistake. If you move it into the correct directory and re-do the add, commit, and push, you should see the file in your repo.

One other possibility—-is this a group project? If you put in a pull request and one of your collaborators made changes and re-pushed, they may have removed the file or placed it in a different folder.

Comment: Thanks Julia. I had ignored the code by mistake. I resolved it by restarting the whole process on PyCharm, then committing and pushing everything together.